# Display array words in a span when success AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have this codes that will display words with checkbox. As you can see they are delimited by comma, and I used split() function to explode the string making it an array. I used for loop to iterate the words, but I'm getting an "undefined" for the words. It should automatically display the words with checkbox but the words display undefined. When I hit refresh, it displays the word properly and the there is a checkbox. I'm not sure where is the problem. Any idea on this?

```
    $(document).on('click', '#wordlistsave', function() 
    {

    var user = $("#getUser").val();
    var title = $("#wordbanktitle").val();
    var word = $("#wordbanklist").val();
    var postID = $("#getPostID").val();
    var words = word.split(", ");


    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {                   
    var dataString = 'user='+user+'&title='+title+'&words='+words[i]+'&id='+postID;

    <?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
      if(words[i])
      {

      $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?= plugins_url('wordlistsave.php', __FILE__) ?>",
      data: dataString,
      cache: true,
      success: function(postID)
      {

      var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", words[i]);
      testBoxDiv.css({"margin-bottom":"5px"});
      testBoxDiv.after().html('<span id="'+words[i]+'" style="cursor:pointer">\
        <img src="./wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/pdfpreview/delete_icon.png" title="Delete word"></span>\
      &nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="words[]" value="'+ words[i]+ '">'+words[i] );
      testBoxDiv.appendTo("#test_container");   

      }
      });
      }


    <?php else: ?>
      alert('Please login.');
    <?php endif; ?>
    }    

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words` is visible from success function, but when it executes you can't be sure for  `i` value because it doesn't execute syncronously.
So, you can pass an extra param, words, to ajax setup dictionary and access it from success function. Like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=plugins_url('wordlistsave.php', __FILE__ )?>",
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    word : words[i],
    success: function(postID)
    {

        var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", this.word);
        testBoxDiv.css({"margin-bottom":"5px"});
        testBoxDiv.after().html('<span id="'+this.word+'" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="./wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/pdfpreview/delete_icon.png" title="Delete word"></span>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="words[]" value="'+ this.word+ '">'+this.word );
        testBoxDiv.appendTo("#test_container"); 

    }
});
```

Comment: nice, it works. I will just adjust the css since it adds a space above the words.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you do not need to construct the data string for $.ajax, you can simply pass the data like:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=plugins_url('wordlistsave.php', __FILE__ )?>",
    data: {
        user: user,
        title: title,
        words: words[i],
        id: postID 
    }
```